# Does forward declaration fix the number of argument?

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ now, and did some experiment for self study.

It seems that if a function is declared with variables assigned by default value, that function does not require arguments for those variables having default value.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c = 3)
{
    return a+b+c;
}

int main()
{
    int q = foo(2,5); //results 10
    printf("result is %d \n", q);
}
```

However, if I do forward declaration, the compiler complains about number of arguments.

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c);

int main()
{
    int q = foo(2,5); //compiler error
    printf("result is %d \n", q);
}

int foo(int a, int b, int c = 3)
{
    return a+b+c;
}
```

> error: too few arguments to function 'int foo(int, int, int)'

Why is it?

Comment: Because the default argument is determined at the point where your function is called, not within the function definition.   So specify the default value in the declaration before `main()`  (i.e. in what you call the "forward declaration") and omit it from the function definition.   A default value specified in the function definition only matters if the entire function definition is visible when the function is called (as in your first example), otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: To add at the confusion, you might add extra declaration with other default value [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a64884f0e9e1330).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the prototype needs to contain the default argument value:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c = 3);
```

And when you *define* the function, you omit it:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a+b+c;
}
```